# AppCompat does not support the current theme features

Tags: java, android, xml, android-appcompat

The following are codes for my android app.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/tb_main"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
         app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
         tools:background="@color/orange" />
```

Activity

```
Private void initView() {
             listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_main);
             floatTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_main_title);
             toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_main);
             setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
             getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
             }
```

I check stackoverflow and most people said this would solve the problem but i'm still facing issue my Nexus 5 API 22 x86(Emulator)-Lollipop but works well on Samsung Galaxy Note 3(Kit Kat)

I have also set to com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3

```
    <style name="FeedTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     </style>
```

Error

```
06-03 22:07:51.759  26306-26306/hopon.com.hopon E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hopon.com.hopon/hopon.com.hopon.activity.FeedItemActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:360)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at hopon.com.hopon.activity.FeedItemActivity.onCreate(FeedItemActivity.java:78)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5226)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Gabriele It's not a duplicate -.- meh~

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this theme should solve your problem

```
<style name="FeedTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

Comment: Tried, but isn't working! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643107/appcompat-does-not-support-the-current-theme