# AppCompat does not support the current theme

Tags: java, android, xml, algorithm, android-layout

My app is running fine on Android N, but is crashing at `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` on Android M:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: true, windowNoTitle: false }
```

Whats odd is that I haven't even edited anything to do with my app's theme, and so this error is very odd:

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>z
    </style>

    <style name="DialogStyle">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.curlybraceapps.ruchir.rescuer, PID: 20394
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.curlybraceapps.ruchir.rescuer/com.curlybraceapps.ruchir.rescuer.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the
>   current theme features: { windowActionBar: false,
>   windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false,
>   windowActionModeOverlay: true, windowNoTitle: false }
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                       **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not
>   support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false,
>   windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false,
>   windowActionModeOverlay: true, windowNoTitle: false }**
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:474)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.curlybraceapps.ruchir.rescuer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:152)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Why is this issue suddenly occurring, even though I haven't changed anything to do with my theme at all?

Comment: did you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the parent theme worked for me

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting same problem so I have update my style like this and its worked.

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```